# Can we find the electric field at the centre of a regular polygon **using polygon rule**?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors

Consider a regular pentagon whose vertices are labelled as $1, 2, 3, 4$ and $5$. Now, let us put a charge +q at each corner. I can understand that the field at the centre $O$ must be zero, from symmetry. Also, by breaking each electric field vector at the centre into two mutually orthogonal components in the plane of the polygon, I can show that the fields cancel out at the center. I have also seen [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108929/electric-field-inside-a-regular-polygon-with-corner-charges) answer.

But can we use the "polygon rule of vector addition" to show that the field at the center vanishes? I am interested in solving the problem without breaking the fields into components or without using the symmetry of the problem. Of course, we have to show that $\vec{1O}+\vec{2O}+\vec{3O}+\vec{4O}+\vec{5O}=\vec{0}$. I have a hunch that the polygon rule must lead to this. Any hint?

Comment: What is the polygon rule ?

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/what-are-the-parallelogram-and-the-polygon-methods

Comment: @RohanNuckchady Thanks, I got the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polygon rule can be definitely used to justify the zero electric field at the center. First of all, note that for any arbitrary configuration of charges (of equal magnitude), located on the unit circle (centered at the origin) at locations A, B, C, D and E, the electric field vector at the center O is proportional to $\vec{AO}+\vec{BO}+\vec{CO}+\vec{DO}+\vec{EO}$. However, this vector lies in the opposite direction of the vector $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}$, which is in the direction of the center of charge (say G), because center of charge is defined as

$$\mathbf r_{\rm COM}=\frac{\displaystyle \sum_1 ^n q_i \mathbf r_i}{\displaystyle \sum _1 ^n q_i}$$

where $\mathbf r_i$ are the position vectors of the charges under consideration. In our case, it's easy to see that

$$\mathbf r_{\rm COM}=\frac{
\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}}{5}$$

Thus, we can say that $\mathbf E\propto -\mathbf r_{\rm COM}$

Now in the case where these charges are placed symmetrically across the unit circle, the value of $\mathbf r_{\rm COM}$ vanishes to become a null vector. Thus, the electric field which, as we discussed, was proportional to $-\mathbf r_{\rm COM}$, bow also vanishes and becomes zero. In fact, these set of arguments can be generalized to any $n$-sided polygon, always yielding the same value (zero) if the electric field.

Comment: But how did you get that $
\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}=0$?

Comment: Since you are not wanting to use symmetry, let's convert this vector summation problem to a complex number problem. Let's assume the vector OA to represent 1. Then OB, OC, OD and OE respectively are $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4$, where $\alpha$ is the fifth root of unity. Summing them gives us $1+\alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4$ which is zero (standard property of roots of unity ([this image](https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/uploads/ZQpU0gjrZL-unity-polygons.png?width=3600) may help)). However, in this approach as well, we have implicitly used components and symmetry.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 (just in case you did not get the ping)